# How to delete a specific <li> of a particular <ul> from a list of several <ul>s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 10-15 unordered lists in my HTML page, each containing a delete button next to each list item.

For each li to be uniquely identifiable, I have assigned to its id: its parent's id and its own category_name.

However, when I perform the remove() -- it doesn't work. The li does not get removed from its parent.

I already have an input box associated with each ul to add li's to the specific ul which is working.

```
<script>

    function remove_category(ident){
        $("#"+ident).remove;     
    }

    function add_category(ul_id, input_id){
        var ul = $("#"+ul_id);
        var added_category = $("#"+input_id).val();
         $(ul)
             .append('<li class="list-group-item" id="'+added_category+'">'+added_category+'<button type="button" id="delete-category-btn" onclick="remove_category('+ul_id+added_category+');"><i class="fa fa-times delete-fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></li>')
    }
</script>
```

The `remove_category()` function does not perform any action.

Comment: check value of `ident` in remove method.

Comment: maybe there are several mistake but first .remove is method so call like $().remove()

Comment: also, try wrapping ul_id and added_category with " quotations when you add category. so something like :

...+" ' "+ul_id+added_category+" ' "+....

Comment: just: onclick="$(this).closest('li').remove();"

Comment: you should try JIJUMON code.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] so we can see what it is that doesn't work.

Comment: And FYI, beyond syntax error, you aren't adding the `ul`'s id to the `li` so the remove method won't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because of the event handler is not taking dynamic element. Use `.on` to make the click event work on dynamic element

Here is the example.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".added-category", function() {
  var parent = $(this).closest("li");
  parent.after("<li>" + parent.html() + "</li>");
});

$(document).on("click", ".remove-category", function() {
  var parent = $(this).closest("li");
  parent.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    some text
    <button class="added-category">Add</button>
    <button class="remove-category">Remove</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you so much! The remove_category() code works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this,

```js
function removeLi(dhis){
  dhis.parent().remove()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li >list 1 <button onclick="removeLi($(this))">remove</button></li>
    <li>list 2 <button onclick="removeLi($(this))">remove</button></li>
    <li >list 3 <button onclick="removeLi($(this))">remove</button></li>
    <li >list 4 <button onclick="removeLi($(this))">remove</button></li>
    <li >list 5 <button onclick="removeLi($(this))">remove</button></li>
</ul>
```